# Encrypt on Solaris, decrypt on Linux

Tags: linux, encryption, solaris

I have encrypted a file on a Solaris server using the encrypt command, with a keyfile generated via pktool (choosing AES-128 as the algorithm). I do not have access to any other encryption utilities on this server. What application(s) could I use to decrypt this file on a more generic Linux server?

EDIT:

Here are the Solaris commands I used:

```
pktool genkey keystore=file outkey=testkeyfile.dat dir=mydir
keytype=aes keylen=128 encrypt -a aes -k mydir/testkeyfile.dat -i mydir/myfile -v -o mydir/myfile.enc
```

I also ran the following to check that the file was correctly encrypted:

```
decrypt -a aes -k mydir/testkeyfile.dat -i mydir/myfile.enc -v -o mydir/myfile2
```

I suspect mcrypt is probably the way to go here, but can anyone advise on the options that I'd need to use?

Comment: have you tried using mcrypt on linux to decrypt it?

Comment: After a bit of further reading that was my first thought as well, but I'm not sure what settings I'd need to use to get it to work.

Comment: @FrankThomas I've now tried using mcrypt on Ubuntu 12.10 but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the openssl command?  I'm almost positive it comes preinstalled on Solaris, possibly somewhere under /usr/sfw/?

Check the official openssl documentation here:

http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html

Or someone else's useful guide:

http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#encrypt-simple

Comment: Like I said, I don't have access to any other encryption utilities on the server. Unfortunately this includes openssl - there is a man page for it on the system, but it only describes how to use it in a compiled program. I am not able to call it from the command line.

Comment: Actually, this is installed and I've got it working (it was in /usr/sfw/bin - whereis only knew about the man page). I still need to successfully decrypt a file on another server. If it works, the bounty is yours.

Comment: Confirmed working on Ubuntu 12.10. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the system tools are not compatible, you could use other cross-platform encrypters.

Some of the best-known tools are
[GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) and
[AES Crypt](http://www.aescrypt.com/), available and compatible across almost all platforms.

Comment: I don't think these are installed on the solaris server in question. I don't have superuser privileges, so I don't think I'd be able to install anything, and in this case I can't get anyone else to do it either.

Comment: You may not need superuser. See [How can I install an RPM without being root?](http://superuser.com/questions/209808/how-can-i-install-an-rpm-without-being-root).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I attempted this with an unrelated rpm but got an error running the make command, presumably because something wasn't in the expected location.

Comment: Yes, not all packages can be installed that way. This should work for GnuPG version 1.4.13 which is portable. You might also just compile from source. See for example this [lightweight implementation](http://www.literatecode.com/aes256).

Answer (score 0):

I have a perl script that will decrypt files encrypted with Solaris' 'encrypt' command and with the arcfour algorithm.  It works on linux.

Comment: This is not enough information to solve the question. Please add where you got the script and how to use it.

Comment: I wrote it.  where can I put it and reference it here.  Could I add the source here?

Comment: I would edit your answer and put it in, as long as you explain what it does and how to use it.